# j_security authentication using cURL

Tags: tomcat, curl, forms-authentication, jdbcrealm

I'm using Tomcat JDBCRealm to authenticated users when they follow a protected page. The authentication works properly when reaching a protected page. Now I'd like to automate this process using cURL. I've written the code below but it doesn't work :

```
$domainUrl = "http://mydomain.com/protectedArea?j_username=john&j_password=doe";
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $domainUrl );
//curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
//curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true); 
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 7 );

$output = curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close ( $ch );
```

In tomcat log we can see only http GET :

```
[07/Aug/2012:11:51:24 +0200] GET http://mydomain.com/protectedArea?j_username=john&j_password=doe HTTP/1.1 200 1618
```

whereas we should have something like that :

```
[07/Aug/2012:11:57:06 +0200] GET http://mydomain.com/protectedArea?j_username=john&j_password=doe HTTP/1.1 200 1516
[07/Aug/2012:11:57:06 +0200] POST http://mydomain.com/j_security_check HTTP/1.1 302 -
```

Does someone have any idea?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Comment: Note: you shouldn't use `JDBCRealm` for anything that really matters. Instead, use `DataSourceRealm` which is configured nearly identically but uses a connection pool and isn't single-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only have a single `curl_exec` call... did you expect a single call to result in two separate requests to the server? You will have to do the following in order to script a form-based login to a spec-compliant server:

1. Make a request to a protected resource. Any one will do.
2. Make a request to `j_security_check` and include `j_username` and `j_password` request parameters. `POST` would be a good idea to avoid web servers logging the credentials. If the authentication is successful, you should get the resource originally requested in #1.
3. Make a request to the protected resource that you truly want to access.